# Do we use the subjunctive with verbs of sense?

Tags: past-tense, subjunctive-mood, sense-verbs, is-it-a-rule, irrealis-were

An ESL student told me she was taught never to use the subjunctive with verbs of sense (*touch, taste, feel*, etc.). So, compare the following sentences:

1. She behaves as though she **were** the boss.
2. I feel as though my hair **were** straw.

In the second example, my student was taught to use *was* instead of *were* because of the verb *feel*.

I have not encountered this “rule” before, so I am unsure whether it is correct or perhaps just a regional usage. Does anyone know whether this is a rule or not?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150227/discussion-on-question-by-leanne-bellamy-do-we-use-the-subjunctive-with-verbs-of); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

> An ESL student told me she was taught never to use the subjunctive
> with verbs of sense (touch, taste, feel, etc.). So, compare the
> following sentences:
>
> She behaves as though she were the boss.
>
> I feel as though my hair were straw.

The use of the subjunctive is correct, but it has nothing to do with the verb.

The subjunctive is used because of "as though", which creates irrealis: she is not the boss and your hair is not straw.

Compare

He runs as if he **were** terrified. It is as though something **were** chasing him.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150228/discussion-on-answer-by-greybeard-do-we-use-the-subjunctive-with-verbs-of-sense); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Thank you @greybeard for your response. To clarify, my understanding of "as though" is the same as yours; however, this student was taught that a verb of sense requires the indicative mood rather than the subjunctive. I am trying to find out whether that is a legitimate rule or not.

Comment: I feel (a verb of sense) is in the indicative, but "my hair were (a verb of state) straw" is the subjunctive as "my hair" is not straw: it only feels that way.